# Factoring a class getter in Python

Tags: python, properties, getter, setter

I have a base abstract class from which 2 other classes should inherit. These child classes should each implement their own setters on a getter-attribute from the base. It would be very nice to not having to (redundantly) re-define the same getter method for each child class, but if they just could inherit the getter and put their own setters on it. Is this viable in Python?
The code would look something like below (which of course throws an Error!):

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0
    @property
    def x(self): return self._x
    
class A(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    @x.setter
    def x(self, newx): self._x += newx

class B(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    @x.setter
    def x(self, newx): self._x -= newx
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to refer to the `property` in the `Base` classe's namespace, so the following should work:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0
    @property
    def x(self): return self._x

class A(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    @Base.x.setter
    def x(self, newx): self._x += newx

class B(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    @Base.x.setter
    def x(self, newx): self._x -= newx
```

And just to demonstrate, in a REPL:

```
>>> class Base:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self._x = 0
...     @property
...     def x(self): return self._x
...
>>> class A(Base):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super().__init__()
...     @Base.x.setter
...     def x(self, newx): self._x += newx
...
>>> class B(Base):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super().__init__()
...     @Base.x.setter
...     def x(self, newx): self._x -= newx
...
>>> base = Base()
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> base.x, a.x, b.x
(0, 0, 0)
>>> base.x = 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>> a.x = 10
>>> b.x = 10
>>> base.x, a.x, b.x
(0, 10, -10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not define the setter on the base class? Just have it raise `NotImplementedError`

I always preferred the
 `x = propertey(getter, setter)`
syntax myself.

You'll then have

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0
    
    def getter(self):
        return self._x

    def setter(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    x = property(getter, setter)
```

Now just write the `setter` methods on the Derived classes.